# how to create a new window automatically in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

It's weird that a function to create a new window works when I use a button to call it and didn't work when something satisfy some condition to call it.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from interface import Ui_Form as uiInterface
from chooseLauncherFile import Ui_Form as uiChooseLauncherFile

class MyInterface(uiInterface):
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setupUi(self.window)

        self.threads = QtCore.QThread()
        self.threads.run = self.init
        self.threads.start()

        self.window.show()

    def init(self):
        self.util = Util(self)
        self.util.detectLauncher()
        self.syncToServer()  #this function should run after main window show

    def chooseLauncherFile(self):
        self.chooseLauncherWindow = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.chooseLauncherUi=MyChooseLauncherFile()
        self.chooseLauncherUi.setupUi(self.chooseLauncherWindow)
        self.chooseLauncherWindow.show()

class MyChooseLauncherFile(uiChooseLauncherFile):
    def confirm(self, item):
        EXEC_FILE = item.text()

class Util():
    def __init__(self, interface):
        self.interface = interface

    def detectLauncher(self):
        if True: #has been simplified here
            self.interface.chooseLauncherFile()
```

these code will make the new child window non-response, but it will be ok when I change the code like following

```
def init(self):
        self.syncToServer()  #this function should run after main window show

self.pushButton.pressed.connect(self.chooseLauncherFile)
#this line come from another file 
#to use a button to call function
```

It's highly appreciate if you could help me make code of top works, in another world, create a new window automatically not using button.

Comment: Please read the guidance on how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: What do you mean automatically? What is the action that needs to be done so the new Window is created?

Comment: @Blinxen my program is to detect whether a file exist, if not exist, create a window to select it manually